# select four item per category mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My schema has the following tables
 **product table**

> productid name

**category table**

> categoryid name parentid

**category_product table**

> categoryid productid

I want to retrieve four record from top categories i.e. immediate child of root category.
I had run following  query but it returns all product.

```
select 
    `pp`.`productid`, count(`pp`.`productid`)
from
    `product` `pp`
        join
    `category_product` `pc` ON `pp`.`productid` = `pc`.`poduct_id`
        join
    `category` `cp` ON `pc`.`category_id` = `cp`.`categoryid`
where
    `cp`.`parent_id` = 1
group by `pp`.`productid`
having count(`pp`.`productid`) < 4 ;
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the results that you are looking for?  "I want to retrieve four record from top categories i.e. immediate child of root category." is not clear.

Comment: root category is parent of all categories

Comment: Example: suppose Electronics and Cloths are child of root category and computer and jeans are child category of electronics and cloths respectively. I want to select four rows from electronics and cloths.

Comment: First focus on making a SQL that returns all the categories ordered so the first four records are the ones you need. Then add LIMIT 4 to the end of that SQL. (See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) I would have written that SQL for you, but your datamodel is not clear to me.